# Create build files (.app & .mobileprovision) to use in iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

My client is using the iPhone Configuration Utility to install builds on their devices. They are asking me for a separate .app and .mobileprovision file. In xCode 4/4.2 whenever I do a build I get a .ipa file. How do I get xCode to spit out the two separately? I tried unzipping the .ipa and sending the included .app file plus the embedded.mobileprovision file from the .app separately. This didn't work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **iPhone Configuration Utility** works great with ***.ipa** files.

The ***.mobileprovision** file is used to code-sign your application. You can create & download it in your Apple-Developer Member Center ([developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)) at **iOS Provisioning Portal -> Provisioning**.

In XCode4 you can use the **Archive** Build (**Project -> Archive**). Make sure you use "iOS Device" as platform. After the archiving is finished, the Xcode Organizer opens and you can select the ***mobileprovision*** file to sign your app & export your app (via "Share") as an **.ipa** file.

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking

.**app file**

Get your app location using `[[NSBundle mainbundle]bundlepath]` there you may find .app file there

**provision profile**

You will have to sign into *iOS provisioning portal* and download it from *provision profile* option